# Data race fail to understand

Tags: go, race-condition, goroutine

Motivation: I have a huge JSON file which I intend to parse and do something with it.

Now, I'm certain there would be some library that would be doing this but I thought of doing this myself to better understand the Go's concurrency constructs.

So my objective is to read the file using `scanner` and pump the data on to `[]byte chan` like this:

```
    // Not the actual code.
    for scanner.Scan() {
       input <- []byte(scanner.Text())
    }
```

I ask more than 1 go-routine to receive data from the `input` chan and unmarshal the JSON and return the result (whether the marshal was a success or not) and also display the progress bar

```
    // not the actual code.
     for {
        bytes := <- input
        if err := json.Unmarshal(bytes); err != nil {
          errorchan <- true
        } else {
           successchan <- true
        }
        progress <-  size_of_byte(bytes)
     }
    
      // now have other go-routine to handle errorchan, successchan and progress thing.
```

All seem logical on paper but when I manage to assemble the code (given below) I see data race and I tried my best to understand how that data race is happening but could not(as I remove some other data races that we present in the code earlier)

```
workers 0xc0000c2000
 Completed 0.000000==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c0000c2048 by goroutine 8:
  mongo_import/race-d.readFile()
      /Users/admin/Documents/goProject/src/mongo_import/race-d/main.go:197 +0x6ff
  mongo_import/race-d.TestReadJson()
      /Users/admin/Documents/goProject/src/mongo_import/race-d/main_test.go:8 +0x47
  testing.tRunner()
      /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.7/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:909 +0x199

Previous write at 0x00c0000c2048 by goroutine 12:
  mongo_import/race-d.(*Worker).trackSuccess()
      /Users/admin/Documents/goProject/src/mongo_import/race-d/main.go:103 +0xc0

Goroutine 8 (running) created at:
  testing.(*T).Run()
      /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.7/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:960 +0x651
  testing.runTests.func1()
      /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.7/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:1202 +0xa6
  testing.tRunner()
      /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.7/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:909 +0x199
  testing.runTests()
      /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.7/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:1200 +0x521
  testing.(*M).Run()
      /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.7/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:1117 +0x2ff
  main.main()
      _testmain.go:44 +0x223

Goroutine 12 (running) created at:
  mongo_import/race-d.(*Worker).Start()
      /Users/admin/Documents/goProject/src/mongo_import/race-d/main.go:72 +0x15f
==================
--- FAIL: TestReadJson (1.18s)
    testing.go:853: race detected during execution of test
FAIL
FAIL    mongo_import/race-d 1.192s
FAIL
```

- The data race in the testing package is something new to me.
- But I'm unable to comprehend why this is resulting in data race (and it's making no sense to me)

  ```
    Previous write at 0x00c0000c2048 by goroutine 12:
  mongo_import/race-d.(*Worker).trackSuccess()
      /Users/admin/Documents/goProject/src/mongo_import/race-d/main.go:103 +0xc0

   Goroutine 12 (running) created at:
  mongo_import/race-d.(*Worker).Start()
      /Users/admin/Documents/goProject/src/mongo_import/race-d/main.go:72 +0x15f
  ```

Code:

Here how the code looks like

```
    package main
    
    import (
        "bufio"
        "encoding/binary"
        "encoding/json"
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "os"
        "sync"
        "time"
    )
    
    // thread that does that job of unmarshal
    type Thread struct {
        w *Worker
    }
    
    // Run the individual thread and process the bytes
    // read for worter.input chan
    func (thread Thread) Run() {
        for {
            bytes, ok := <-thread.w.input
            if !ok {
                return
            }
    
            var data map[string]interface{}
            if err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &data); err != nil {
                thread.w.errorChan <- true
            } else {
                thread.w.successChan <- true
            }
    
            thread.w.progress <- int64(binary.Size(bytes))
            // do other thing
            // like insert in db etc.
        }
    }
    
    // worker that
    type Worker struct {
        errmutex      sync.Mutex
        succmutex     sync.Mutex
        progmutex     sync.Mutex
        wg            sync.WaitGroup
        done          bool
        workers       int
        fileSize      int64
        completedByte int64
        errorCount    int
        successCount  int
        input         chan []byte
        progress      chan int64
        errorChan     chan bool
        successChan   chan bool
    }
    
    // NewWorker
    func NewWorker(count int) *Worker {
        return &Worker{workers: count}
    }
    
    // start the worker
    func (w *Worker) Start() {
        fmt.Printf("workers %p\n", w)
        w.wg.Add(1)
        go w.display()
        w.wg.Add(1)
        go w.trackProgress()
        w.wg.Add(1)
        go w.trackSuccess()
        w.wg.Add(1)
        go w.trackError()
        w.wg.Add(1)
        go w.Spawn()
        w.wg.Wait()
    }
    
    // add the error count
    func (w *Worker) trackError() {
        w.wg.Done()
        for {
            _, ok := <-w.errorChan
            if !ok {
                return
            }
            w.errmutex.Lock()
            w.errorCount = w.errorCount + 1
            w.errmutex.Unlock()
        }
    }
    
    // add the success count
    func (w *Worker) trackSuccess() {
        defer w.wg.Done()
        for {
            _, ok := <-w.successChan
            if !ok {
                return
            }
            w.succmutex.Lock()
            w.successCount += 1
            w.succmutex.Unlock()
        }
    }
    
    // spawn individual thread to process the bytes
    func (w *Worker) Spawn() {
        defer w.wg.Done()
        defer w.clean()
        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        for i := 0; i < w.workers; i++ {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func() {
                defer wg.Done()
                Thread{w: w}.Run()
            }()
        }
    
        wg.Wait()
    
    }
    
    // close the other open chan
    func (w *Worker) clean() {
        close(w.errorChan)
        close(w.successChan)
        close(w.progress)
    }
    
    // close the input chan
    func (w *Worker) Done() {
        close(w.input)
    }
    
    // sum the total byte we have processed
    func (w *Worker) trackProgress() {
        defer w.wg.Done()
        for {
            read, ok := <-w.progress
            if !ok {
                w.done = true
                return
            }
            w.progmutex.Lock()
            w.completedByte += read
            w.progmutex.Unlock()
    
        }
    }
    
    // display the progress bar
    func (w *Worker) display() {
        defer w.wg.Done()
        for !w.done {
            w.progmutex.Lock()
            percentage := (float64(w.completedByte) / float64(w.fileSize)) * 100
            w.progmutex.Unlock()
            fmt.Printf("\r Completed %f", percentage)
            time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        }
    }
    
    func readFile(path string) map[string]int {
        handler, err := os.Open(path)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer handler.Close()
        worker := &Worker{workers: 2}
        worker.input = make(chan []byte, 2)
        worker.progress = make(chan int64, 1)
        worker.errorChan = make(chan bool, 1)
        worker.successChan = make(chan bool, 1)
    
        if fi, err := handler.Stat(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        } else {
            worker.fileSize = fi.Size()
        }
    
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(handler)
        go worker.Start()
        for scanner.Scan() {
            worker.input <- []byte(scanner.Text())
        }
    
        worker.Done()
        if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
            return nil
        }
    
        return map[string]int{
            "error":   worker.errorCount,
            "success": worker.successCount,
        }
    }
    
    func main() {
        readFile("dump.json")
    }
```

and Test Code

```
    package main // main_test.go
    
    import (
        "testing"
    )
    
    func TestReadJson(t *testing.T) {
        data := readFile("dump2.json")
        if data == nil {
            t.Error("we got a nil data")
        }
    }
```

And here the Sample `dump2.json` data

```
{"name": "tutorialspoint10"}
{"name":"tutorialspoint2", "age": 15}
{"name":"tutorialspoint3", "age": 25}
{"name":"tutorialspoint4", "age": 28}
{"name":"tutorialspoint5", "age": 40}
{"name": "tutorialspoint6"}
{"name":"tutorialspoint8", "age": 7}
{"name":"tutorialspoint4", "age": 55}
{"name":"tutorialspoint1","age":4}
{"name":"tutorialspoint2"}
```

Lastly, I know the code posted here has to be minimalist but I tried my best to keep the code minimalist(which is extracted from the original project). I'm not sure how (or capable as of now) to minimize it even further.

Comment: The race detector output points directly to the problem lines.  `readFile` reads the `successCount` field concurrently with the write in `trackSuccess`.

Comment: Aside from the race, the input you showed is an nd-json file, and you can use a decoder to unmarshal it line by line iteratively and pass the unmarshaled objects to the goroutines for processing.

Comment: so...... is it faster ?

Comment: `Now, I'm certain there would be some library that would be doing this` -- why are you certain about that? Reading a file is a serial operation, and reading the json is nearly always going to be far slower than decoding, so there's no need to schedule multiple decoders which are all going to be waiting on the slowest operation.

Comment: @mh-cbon, it will eliminate double-parsing the input (once for scanner and once for the unmarshaler), there will be only one decoder instead of one for each goroutine, and there will be less decoder setup time (once for stream instead of once for each line), so yes.

Comment: Can you paste the lines `/mongo_import/race-d/main.go:103` and `mongo_import/race-d/main.go:72`?

Comment: @JimB so essentially I'm parsing the JSON and inserting on cosmos DB that uses MongoDB API so mongoimport would work here too. I'm sorry If I did not mention that.

And yes reading from a file has to be serial there is no 2 way about it

Comment: @MuffinTop well it helps I'm not able to understand it since the point where I'm using `successCount` on readFile I'm of the belief that all the goroutine would be completed. Since I'm calling `worker.Done()` this shutdown all the goroutine.

Comment: @BurakSerdar my question was to Noobie. Sorry i misguided you. I understood upfront what you described but hoped that by asking to OP he would try to measure it and show back the results here for future readers. but yeah... maybe i am hoping too much, too often.

Comment: `Since I'm calling worker.Done() this shutdown all the goroutine` the current implementation of `worker.Done` does not wait for routines to end, it only instructs, sends a signal, to begin the exit sequence ASAP.

Answer (score -2):

You need a read lock at line main.go:197

`"success": worker.successCount,`

As the log says. You try to read while another go-routine try to write.
`/Users/admin/Documents/goProject/src/mongo_import/race-d/main.go:197`

A short explanation:

https://dev.to/wagslane/golang-mutexes-what-is-rwmutex-for-57a0

It may be better in this situation to use Atomic.
https://gobyexample.com/atomic-counters

Comment: The point is the Why? why do I need a lock because the go-routine are already completed when I'm using worker.successCount as I'm calling `worker.Done`  before?

Comment: Atomics would only make concurrent access safe; it would not provide the useful result if the goroutines are not properly synchronized in the first place (which they aren't)

Comment: All you do in worker.Done is closing the channel. So if you are inside the channel loop you still processing, and if it's a buffered channel all the messages in the buffer will be processed before the channel for loop exit. You need to use context.Context to stop something in the middle.